# Submit button only sees the multiplequestions as onequestion using php and database

Tags: php, mysql, database, multiple-choice, submit-button

so I have this problem. When I select a radio button of question one for example it selects the radio button. But when I select another radio button from a different question, the first radio button that I've selected isn't selected anymore and the other radio button is selected. 
I've tried searching for a solution,but I can't find any. 
It's for a school project, we have to make a poll. 
Here's the code:

```
<?php

mysql_connect("  ", "    ", "   ");
mysql_select_db("  ") or die(mysql_error());

if(isset($_POST['verzenden'])) {
$query="UPDATE optie SET stemmen = stemmen + 1 WHERE id='" . $_POST['item']. "'";
}
if(mysql_query($query)){
echo"Stem opgeslagen! <br /><br/>";
} else {
echo"Fout tijdens opslaan stem!<br /><br/>";
}

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM poll");

while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

echo"<b>" . $data['vraag'] . "</b><br/><br />";

echo"<form method='post' action=''>";
echo "<fieldset>";

$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM optie WHERE poll ='" . $data['id'] . "'");
while($data2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)){
echo"<input type='radio' name='item' value='" . $data2['id'] . "'/>" . $data2['optie'] . "<br />";
}
echo"<br/>";
echo"</fieldset>";
}
?>
<input type='submit' name='verzenden' value='Verzenden'>
</form>

<a href="checkbox.php">Ga verder</a>
```

I hope that someone can help me.
bye, 
Catherine

Comment: you need to give different name for each radio button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's happening because all of your radio button sets have the same name: `item`. Here are a couple ways you can make the radio button sets unique; pick the one that's best for you.

1. Append the `poll.id` value to each button name:

   ```
   $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM optie WHERE poll ='" . $data['id'] . "'");
   while($data2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)){
     echo"<input type='radio' name='item_" . $data['id'] . "' value='" . $data2['id'] . "'/>" . $data2['optie'] . "<br />";
   }
   ```
2. Append a sequence number to each button name:

   ```
   $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM optie WHERE poll ='" . $data['id'] . "'");
   $buttonNumber = 0;
   while($data2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)){
     ++$buttonNumber;
     echo"<input type='radio' name='item_$buttonNumber' value='" . $data2['id'] . "'/>" . $data2['optie'] . "<br />";
   }
   ```

Finally, note that the `mysql_query` family of functions is deprecated because it can leave you vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. See [here](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) and other places for information about using `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: Thnx!I used the first one, but now it doesn't submit the votes anymore. (I don't see the votes in the database) The second one doesn't work. Can you help me?

Comment: Sorry, I left out the semicolon at the end of the `++$buttonNumber` line on option #2; that's probably the problem there. I've edited the answer to fix this. The code accompanying your question updates based on *one* radio button set named `item`. That was a problem because you needed *multiple* radio button sets. Now that you have them, you can't just look for `$_POST['item']`. Try a "view source" when your page displays and you'll see how the radio buttons are named. You have to go through the `$_POST` array looking for these new radio button names.

Comment: I got the names, but how can I write them in the $_POST?

Comment: Sorry - we seem to be in very different time zones, or at least we keep different hours :) If the names of your radio buttons are for example `item_1` and `item_333` and `item_27` then they should already be in `$_POST` as `$_POST['item_1']` and `$_POST['item_333']` and `$_POST['item_27']` and so forth. Try a `print_r($_POST)` in your code that handles the `verzenden` button click - that will show you what's in `$_POST`.

Comment: It's okay, yeah :) can you give me a example of the print_r($_POST)?

Comment: Just add this line: `print_r($_POST);`. Put it before your `INSERT` or `UPDATE` query. It should show up on your page. If you have a redirect after your `INSERT` or `UPDATE` just comment it out so you'll get the same page back.

Comment: Okay, thnx! I'm going to try that

Answer (score 0):

You should use different name for each set of radio buttons,

Change your radio button to something like below ,

```
echo"<input type='radio' name='item_". $data2['id'] ."' value='" . $data2['id'] . "'/>
```

this may work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems below lines should be before first `while` loop

```
echo"<form method='post' action=''>";
echo "<fieldset>";
```